Is the following mixed fraction equation correct?

I am wondering if the plus sign is understood in mixed fractions. So it is not written.

This is an equality, not an equation. It is true. This is how mixed fractions work, yes. See here about mixed fractions.

Warning: when you get to algebra, you'll be told that $a{b\over c}$ means $a\times{b\over c}$, not $a+{b\over c}$.

For an extremely basic definition, a mixed fraction represents integer division. The non fraction whole number part at the front, here 2 is the quotient and 1 is the remainder, when 5 is divided by 2. Hence $\frac{5}{2}=2\frac{1}{2}$
